# Powerline: display selected window's mode line in all windows

Tags: mode-line, powerline, mode-line-format

I know this is a slightly odd request, but I'd like to make all the mode lines for windows within a frame identical. I'm using powerline with the default spacemacs theme.

So, if I have three windows open with three different active buffers, I'd like the mode lines for all three to show information about the buffer in the **currently selected** window. (And if I select a new window, they should all change.)

I got the inactive/active styles to line up by redefining `powerline-selected-window-active` to always return `t`, but I can't figure out how to point them at the selected window's buffer rather than their own active buffer.